# How to greyout FloatingActionButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to greyout a FloatingActionButton in Flutter. How do I do that?

[image]

Changing the `onPress` to null doesn't work:

```
floatingActionButton: const FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: null,
  child: Icon(Icons.add),
)
```

Comment: As a matter of interest, why do you want to grey it out rather than just not display it? This would seem to be more of a UI design issue. I would imagine that if it made UI sense to grey it out, the enable/disable property would have been implemented in the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two options....

1. you can specify the background colour as grey just like this:

```
floatingActionButton: const FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: null,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          
        ),
```

2. You can wrap it with Opacity widget just like this:

```
floatingActionButton: const Opacity(
        opacity: .3,//level of opacity 0~1
          child:  FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: null,
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Seems that FloatingActionButton does not supports built-in greyout functionality, handling it directly should be the correct use case. thanks!